# Последовательность рандомных элементов в двумерном масиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть двумерный масив вида

```
let array = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Нужна функция, которая позволит получить массив с индексами рандомно выбранных элементов.

Результат должен выглядеть примерно так

```
let result = getRandomElements(arr, 5)
```

Где 5 это количество элементов

```
result = [[1,3], [3, 1], [2,1], [3,3], [2, 2]]
```

Comment: и с чем трудность?

Comment: Самое трудное - название функции - уже сделано.

Comment: Нужно взять 5 рандомных элементов из масива и они не должны повторяться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cмотрите на них как на одномерный массив индексов от нуля до `(NxM - 1)`.

Заполните массив из пяти элементов случайными числами из этого массива, проверяя, что одинаковых нет. Потом пересчитайте обратно в индексы двумерного массива.

Если нужно много случайных элементов, например, больше четверти, то имеет смысл весь исходный массив индексов перемешать и взять первые `K`.